# Combating Traffic analysis Msc Dissertation ideas

Tags: anonymity, traffic-analysis

I have started my MSc dissertation on anonymity (how to beat traffic analysis techniques) and i'm looking for practical ideas.  What tactics and software technology would be that guarantees private and confidential access to the web?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the purpose of this site. It is not a forum for having discussions. I suggest you take this [tour](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/tour) to better understand our site.

Comment: Anyway, part of the point of a master thesis is for you to learn how to research and review existing literature.